# mysql error 1066

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1066

```
$id=$_GET["id"];
$query= "
SELECT
blomster_produkter.blomster_produkt_id,
blomster_produkter.blomster_produkt_navn,
blomster_produkter.blomster_produkt_pris
FROM
blomster_produkter
INNER JOIN blomster_produkter ON 
blomster_produkter.FK_blomster_produkt_id=blomster_produkter.blomster_produkt_navn     
blomster_produkter.FK_blomster_produkt_id=blomster_produkter.blomster_produkt_pris
blomster_produkter.FK_blomster_produkt_id=blomster_produkter.blomster_produkt_id
WHERE FK_blomster_kategori_id=$id";
```

Why is this throwing me an mysql error  1066?

(also sorry if i am missing some important stuff, this is the first question i am asking on stackoverflow)

Comment: what error ? can write this error _

Comment: thats the The Norman invasion error

Answer (score 8):

0.1 seconds of googling: "mysql error 1066" - not unique table name/alias

```
    FROM
    blomster_produkter   <--table #1
    INNER JOIN blomster_produkter ON   <-table #2
```

you cannot join a table to itself, or re-use the same table name in a join, without using an alias:

```
FROM blomster_produkter
INNER JOIN blomster_produkter AS someothername ON
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- the alias
```

and then changing table references as necessary in your join conditions.

As well, note that you are wide open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1066 is "Not Unique table/alias"

this is because you are join a table with itself without making aliases, you must do aliases like:

```
SELECT
    bp1.blomster_produkt_id,
    bp1.blomster_produkt_navn,
    bp1.blomster_produkt_pris
    FROM
    blomster_produkter bp1
    INNER JOIN blomster_produkter bp2 ON
    bp1.FK_blomster_produkt_id=bp2.blomster_produkt_navn [...]
```